# How can I fix the TypeError in the given code?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, base64

I am getting "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" at line `self['oauth_body_hash'] = base64.b64encode(sha1(self.body).digest())`

```
def sign_request(self, signature_method, consumer, token):
 #Set the signature parameter to the result of sign.
 if not self.is_form_encoded:
   self['oauth_body_hash'] = base64.b64encode(sha1(self.body).digest())

 if 'oauth_consumer_key' not in self:
   self['oauth_consumer_key] = consumer.key
 
 if token and 'oauth_token' not in self:
   self['oauth_token'] = token.key

 self['oauth_signature_method'] = signature_method.name
 self['oauth_signature'] = signature_method.sign(self, consumer, token)
```

These things I have tried:

```
1)self['oauth_body_hash'] = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(str.encode(self.body)).digest())
2)self['oauth_body_hash'] = base64.encodestring(hashlib.sha256(self.body.encode('UTF-8')).digest().strip())
```

Comment: what is the type of self.body?

try: `str(self.body).encode('UTF-8')`

Comment: In self.body, the type of body is 'bytes', also I tried the snippet                                       
```self['oauth_body_hash'] = base64.b64encode(str(self.body).encode('UTF-8'))``` Is this how you wanted me to try it? cause it generates                                                   
    ```API Error [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]```  If this is not how you intended me to try, could you please post that line along with your fix .

Comment: if  self.body type is bytes you should be able to use it as argument of sha1 function

`base64.b64encode(sha1(self.body).digest())`

Comment: yeah but I get the "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" as explained above

Comment: you have string representation of bytes -
 try this :
`base64.b64encode(sha1(self.body.decode().encode("utf-8")).digest())`